# Function "createCampaign" not Found

Tags: reactjs, solidity, smartcontracts, react-context

[image: Error in the Browse console][image: The console.log show the object, but the contract dont receive][Repository](https://github.com/CharlieCidral/Funding/)

It is a form for create a campaign, being sent to the created contract. It should appear in the events of the contract created through the thirdweb.

Comment: Please check your contract u have mispelled `createCampaign` as `createCampaing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's misspelled...

createCampaing

[image]

Comment: It worked. I just had to redeploy and add the new contract key. went unnoticed. Thanks.